# SQL Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with this code:

```
if($sql = $this->database->query("SELECT * FROM warenkorb_artikel WHERE WarenkorbID = '".$erg['WarenkorbID']."'"))
{
    while($erg = $sql->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        [...]
    }                    
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object
>   in [...] on the lin where the "while($eg = $sql->fetch_assoc())" is.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: your query failed and you need to find out why that is; check for errors

Comment: $sql->fetch_assoc($sql) .You missed $sql to pass through fetch_assoc function .

Comment: I thought the If would not be true, if the query fails. ?

Comment: @BikashP That is not correct. If the query succeeded, `$sql` is itself a result resource and has a `->fetch_assoc()` method that takes no argument.

Comment: `$this->database->fetch_assoc()` try like this.

Comment: @NiklasRiecken Is this exactly the code producing the error? It does not look like it would be possible to enter the `if () {}` block to call `fetch_assoc()` on query failure because `$sql` would be false. Is there intervening code which modifies `$sql`?

Comment: No, not `$this->database->fetch_assoc()`. That is not correct, because `fetch_assoc()` can only be called on result resource objects `($sql)`, not connection objects (`$this->database`).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski hmm i think query is running using this `$this->database` therefore i think `fetch_assoc` also need this obj.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This is the Code, reproducing the error, yes - there is nothing running inbetween or changing the $sql

Comment: You also seem to be re-using `$erg` That looks dangerous

Comment: @HamzaZafeer `query()` returns a result resource object on success, and it is that object on which one calls `fetch_assoc()`. Examples here. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc-examples

Comment: Yes I am reusing $erg - allways sequentually. otherwise i would need a thousand of different variables - dont see the point that this is dangerous. 

I have exactly the code shown above, but still the error... I try to print out the content of $sql

Comment: About `$erg` as @RiggsFolly noted - does the `query()` call occur inside another loop? If so, that is certain to cause it to fail after one iteration, because `$erg` is expected to be one array but then becomes a different one.

Comment: The content of $sql is this:

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#76 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(6)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Not its not running insie a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break things down so you can capture any errors you make in a query that are returned by the `mysqli` API.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM warenkorb_artikel 
        WHERE WarenkorbID = '{$erg['WarenkorbID']}'";

$result = $this->database->query($sql);

if ( $result === false ) {
    echo $this->database->error;
    exit;
}

// do you really need a while loop, as it look like you might be
// selecting a row using a unique key?

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         [...]
}
```

Comment: just way too many unknowns, I sure hope this solves it. See my last 2 comments to the OP under the question. Edit: I stood around the question long enough. I hope we see a green ticky! ciao!

Comment: no idea. they tag as mysqli and probably using PDO or (heaven forbid) mysql_ to connect with. It's the best $64,000 question ever. OP's not responding so they're either trying to fix it or have run off to the local bar.

Comment: Trying to fix it... no beer... -,- nearly there

Comment: I guess my last 2 comments were irrelevant then. I should probably delete them as they seem to be taking up space for nothing. Edit: deleted.

Comment: i just wrote my code again. Same variable names but the way RiggsFoly wriote it - first the SQL, then the Query to the result, then check the result. Not it is working...